# Zend Framework EmailAddress validator in array notation

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework, zend-validate

I'm looking for form validation syntax for an Email address in array notation.

This is what i have currently.

```
 $this->addElement('text', 'email', array(
    'placeholder' => 'email address',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array(
        array('name', 'StringTags'),
        arary('name', 'StringTrim'),
    ),
    'validators' => array('EmailAddress')
 ));
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,
Daniel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need wrap it in one more array:

```
'validators' => array(array('EmailAddress')),
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm finding that zend's documentation is pretty poor.

Comment: would you happen to know the syntax of a decorator that holds a description for a field??